# Shabbat key braces (suspenders)

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

I figure that this is a fairly straightforward question: does anyone make braces (American: suspenders) which serve the same purpose as a [Shabbat belt](https://smile.amazon.com/Judaic-Mosaic-Shabbos-Adjustable-White/dp/B01DLO64ZG/ref=pd_ybh_a_22?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=DQ2VV7YD94DBCS9T12SV) ?

Comment: Of possible interest - https://www.haaretz.com/1.5041294

Comment: I am not familiar with the halachos of carrying on Shabbos (I just avoid the entire problem in general; no eiruv here where I live), but could you just wrap the key ring around the suspender straps? Or does it need to be a specific product _exactly_ like the Shabbos key belt?

Comment: @ezra, it should serve as a functional part of the clothing. As such, I can't use a key belt, because it would be redundant with my braces. I figure I could make one, if nothing's available, but I'd rather purchase

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt That's cool that you wear suspenders. :)